# PDO Query on joined tables when column names are the same

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm running a query via PDO on a pair of joined tables like so:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.id, table1.foo, table1.bar 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.bar = table2.id;
```

Both tables have an `id` column so when I run `fetchAll()` the associative array only contains one `id` field. This is because the first is overwritten by the second.

Is there a way to obtain both `id` fields? Perhaps by having the table name included in the array keys...

Comment: There are no "PDO queries". PDO is not a database by any means but a mere API

Comment: I understand that. I used the phrase "PDO Query" to indicate I was running the query over PDO should it be relevant to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use aliases

```
SELECT table1.id as t1id, table2.id as t2id
--etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT table1.id AS idtable1, table2.id AS idtable2, table1.foo, table1.bar 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.bar = table2.id;
```